# Can't access nested resource 'comments' in rails 3.0.1

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, formtastic

I hope you can help me.

*/config/routes.rb*:

```
resources :deadlines do  
  resources :comments  
end
```

*/model/comment.rb*:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  

  belongs_to :post, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "post_id"  

end
```

*/model/post.rb*:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  

  has_many :comments  

end
```

When I want to visit `http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments/new` I get:

```
undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x4889d18>:0x4887138> in _form.html
```

I use 'formtastic' and `the _form.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<% semantic_form_for [@comment] do |form| %>  
  <% form.inputs do %>  
    <%= form.input :content %>  
  <% end %>  

  <% form.buttons do %>  
    <%= form.commit_button %>  
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your other model `Post` or `Deadline`? Assuming it is `Post`:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Run `rake routes` in the terminal to see all your routes. Further info:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects

Syntax for nested resources is:

```
<% semantic_form_for [@post, @comment] do |form| %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It still gives me the error: undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x465cca8>:0x465b850>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% semantic_form_for [@post, @comment] do |form| %>
2:   <% form.inputs do %>
3:     <%= form.input :contentvb%>
4:   <% end %>

Comment: Try adding `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])` to your comments controller new action.

Comment: Hey Heikki I still got a problem here: When I push the 'create comment' button this shows up: undefined method `comment_url' for #<CommentsController:0x476f0e8>. NoMethodError in CommentsController#create. app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:50:in `create'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:48:in `create'

Comment: I added some relevant links to Rails Guides which should clarify how the urls are constructed with routing helpers or from objects. However, this new problem isn't really part of the original question.

Comment: Hey Heikki, could you help me again? I posted a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616982/nested-forms-nomethoderror-in-formtastic